# click 1 times but alert multiple times in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i run code below , click **open** 5 times and click **close** 4 times then click **alert**. 
i expected that alert function run 1 times but it run 5 times **why?** , how to prevent this problem?

code contains 3 buttons that by click **open** ,shows two buttons including **close** and **alert** button and by click **close** hides **alert** and **close** button and by click **alert**,alerts 1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close-but").css("display","none");
    $(".alert").css("display","none");
  $(".open-but").click(function(){
    $(".alert").click(function(){
        alert("1");
    });    
    $(".open-but").css("display","none");
    $(".close-but").css("display","flex");
    $(".alert").css("display","flex");
 });
 $(".close-but").click(function(){
    $(".close-but").css("display","none");
    $(".alert").css("display","none");
    $(".open-but").css("display","flex");
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <button class="open-but">open</button>
  <button class="close-but">close</button>
  <br/>
  <button class="alert">alert</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced `$(".alert").click()`
Every time you hit `.open-but` it assigns an event handler for `alert` button. You should assign `$(".alert").click()` once only. So place this outside of `$(".open-but").click()` as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".close-but").css("display", "none");
        
        $(".alert").css("display", "none");
        
        $(".open-but").click(function() {          
          
          $(".open-but").css("display", "none");
          $(".close-but").css("display", "flex");
          $(".alert").css("display", "flex");
        });
        
        $(".close-but").click(function() {
          $(".close-but").css("display", "none");
          $(".alert").css("display", "none");
          $(".open-but").css("display", "flex");
        });
        
        $(".alert").click(function() {
            alert("1");
          });
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <button class="open-but">open</button>
    <button class="close-but">close</button>
    <br />
    <button class="alert">alert</button>
  </body>

</html>
```